# Key won't turn to off position on 2010 Chevy Aveo

Tags: chevrolet, ignition-key, aveo

I have a 2010 Chevy Aveo and the key will not turn to the off position. It starts and drives but when you try to turn it off it will not turn past the accessory position to the off position. When the car has been sitting overnight the battery goes dead and it needs to be jump started.

Comment: Is this an automatic? If so, the problem probably lies with the mechanism in the shifter which does not allow you to turn the key off all the way without it being in park.

Comment: In addition to what Paulster2 said, it could be that you aren't removing the key right. I hate to ask, but the car is in Park and do you push the key in when twisting it? Sorry if it sounds silly, I just want to make sure we are covering all the bases.

Comment: This is apparently a not uncommon issue in  Aveos. .Some people report that pushing the shifter , in some cases to the left while removing the key works.

Answer (score 3):

GM Provides a flow chart to help you out.

TL;DR The car probably doesn't think you're in park.

> Ignition Key Cannot Be Inserted, Rotated, or Removed from the Ignition
>   Lock Cylinder
>
> Step
>
> Action
>
> Yes
>
> No
>
> 1)
>
> Ensure the transmission shift lever is in the PARK position and the 
>   steering column is NOT in the locked position.
>   Verify the ignition key cannot be removed from the ignition lock cylinder.
>
> Can the ignition key be removed from the ignition lock cylinder?
>
> Go to Step 4
>
> Go to Step 2
>
> 2)
>
> Verify the ignition key cannot be turned to the OFF position.
>
> Can the ignition key be turned to the OFF position?
>
> Go to Step 3
>
> Go to Step 7
>
> 3)
>
> Verify the ignition key cannot be removed from the ignition lock
>   cylinder.
>
> Can the ignition key be removed from the ignition lock cylinder?
>
> Go to Step 7
>
> Go to Step 12
>
> 4)
>
> Verify the ignition key cannot be fully inserted and rotated without
>   sticking in any position.
>
> Can the ignition key be fully inserted into the ignition lock cylinder
>   and be rotated without sticking in any position?
>
> Go to Step 7
>
> Go to Step 5
>
> 5)
>
> Inspect for an incorrect, worn, or damaged ignition key.
>
> Is the ignition key incorrect, worn, or damaged?
>
> Go to Step 10
>
> Go to Step 6
>
> 6)
>
> Inspect the ignition key. Clean the entire middle groove area of the
>   side milled ignition key.
>
> Can the cleaned key be fully inserted into the ignition lock cylinder
>   and be rotated without sticking in any position?
>
> Go to Step 13
>
> Go to Step 12
>
> 7)
>
> Verify the adjustment of the shift control cable. Refer to Range
>   Selector Lever Cable Adjustment.
>
> Can the ignition key be turned to the OFF position and be removed?
>
> Go to Step 13
>
> Go to Step 8
>
> 8)
>
> Attempt to override the ignition lock solenoid on the ignition and
>   start switch housing.
>
> Can the ignition key be turned to the OFF position and be removed?
>
> Go to Step 9
>
> Go to Step 12
>
> 9)
>
> Inspect the electrical system for improper operation. Refer to
>   Ignition Can/Cannot Be Turned Off with Transmission in Any Gear and
>   Testing for Intermittent Conditions and Poor Connections.
>
> Can the ignition key be turned to the OFF position and be removed?
>
> Go to Step 13
>
> Go to Step 11
>
> 10)
>
> Replace the ignition key.
>
> Did you complete the repair?
>
> Go to Step 13
>
> —
>
> 11)
>
> Replace the floor shifter. Refer to Gearshift Control Lever
>   Replacement.
>
> Did you complete the repair?
>
> Go to Step 13
>
> —
>
> 12)
>
> Replace the ignition lock cylinder. Refer to Ignition Lock Cylinder
>   Replacement.
>
> Did you complete the repair?
>
> Go to Step 13
>
> —
>
> 13)
>
> Operate the system in order to verify the repair.
>
> Did you correct the condition?
>
> System OK
>
> —